# C# BLE DeviceConnectionChanged event fires multiple times until shutoff device

Tags: c#, winforms, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I connected to a device and read data successfully. Then I shutoff device, `DeviceConnectionChanged` event fire with `Disconnected` connection status, then turn on device, `DeviceConnectionChanged` event fire with `Connected` connection status, after that loop `Connected` then `Disconnected`, ... until shutoff device.

This is connect function:

```
    public async Task<ConnectionResult> ConnectAsync(string deviceId, Guid serviceUUID)
    {
        _device = await BluetoothLEDevice.FromIdAsync(deviceId);
        if (_device == null)
        {
            return new Schema.ConnectionResult()
            {
                IsConnected = false,
                ErrorMessage = "Could not find specified device"
            };
        }

        if (!_device.DeviceInformation.Pairing.IsPaired)
        {
            _device = null;
            return new Schema.ConnectionResult()
            {
                IsConnected = false,
                ErrorMessage = "Device is not paired"
            };
        }

        _device.ConnectionStatusChanged -= DeviceConnectionStatusChanged;
        _device.ConnectionStatusChanged += DeviceConnectionStatusChanged; // <===== event here

        ... 
    }

    private void DeviceConnectionStatusChanged(BluetoothLEDevice sender, object args)
    {
        OnConnectionStatusChanged(new ConnectionStatusChangedEventArgs()
        {
            IsConnected = sender != null && (sender.ConnectionStatus == BluetoothConnectionStatus.Connected)
        }); // <==== always fire after reconnect
    }


    public event EventHandler<Events.ConnectionStatusChangedEventArgs> ConnectionStatusChanged;

    protected virtual void OnConnectionStatusChanged(Events.ConnectionStatusChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ConnectionStatusChanged?.Invoke(this, e);
    }
```

I want to auto reconnect and read data when device available. How can I do that?

Comment: Use a timer on `ConnectAsync`?

Comment: No, connect when I click Connect button, then add event handler when connect status changed